# searching for the c++ in a string (regular expression)

Tags: regular-expression, r

I want to find if a string contains c++ in it (regular expression). what pattern should I use in grep function in R?

This is my error:

```
Error in grep(pattern = "c++", x = df[trow, "modeling"]) : 
invalid regular expression 'c++', reason 'Invalid use of repetition operators'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to grep for fixed strings use `fgrep` or `grep -F` instead. If you want to use `grep` the meta-characters like `+` needs to be escaped; there are various possibilities for that, e.g. `c[+][+]`.

Answer (score 2):

Janis is right that you're wanting to match regex meta characters, so will need to escape them, What's been missed though is that you're in the R environment. In that case, you need **fixed**:

```
grep(pattern = "c++", x = df[trow, "modeling"], fixed=TRUE)
```

You do realize that there's help available. Try these:

```
?grep
?regexp
```